# put content inside a div with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an easy question, i have a div with some id, and inside there some different contents, that ends with some span separator, i want them to put in a div with class slide, anyway here is the structure to make it more clear:

```
<div id="adv">
 content 1 
 <span class="separator"></span>
 content 2
 <span class="separator"></span>
 etc...
</div>
```

but i want it to have this structure:

```
<div id="adv">
 <div class="slide">
  content 1 
  <span class="separator"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="slide">
  content 2 
  <span class="separator"></span>
 </div>
 etc...
</div>
```

BTW, there is no need in spans with class separator, just content is enough for me, inside a div with class slide

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: What kind of content is it? If you could share a real-life example you would help us help you!

Comment: @shef there are just some text and links(can be changed by order) inside the content, but all theres contents are divided by this span with class separator

Comment: @Vega sorry didnt know though :) im not that experienced in jquery and javascript, thus i thought, maybe there is an easy way

Comment: Do you want to inject new divs inside the "adv" one?

Comment: @davidbuzatto yes, in exactly the way it is in my question

Comment: I think I understood... You want to transform your first code to the second one?

Comment: @davidbuzatto yes, exactly

Comment: @Vega u can have a look at the example here: http://vteem.net/photo/25-0-74 in a top left corner, there is some kind of slider, with changing there the slides, with links, the div with id reklama, and here with mistakes: http://vteem.net/photo/12-0-78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#adv").html( 
        $.map(
            $("#adv").html().split('<span class="separator"></span>'),
            function(content) {
                return '<div class="slide">' + content + '<span class="separator"></span></div>';
            }
        ).join("")
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

To just insert new divs in the first one, you can use something like this:

```
$( "#adv" ).append( createNewDiv( "foo" ) );
$( "#adv" ).append( createNewDiv( "bar" ) );

function createNewDiv( content ) {

    var $div = $( '<div class="slide">' + content + '</div>' );
    var $span = $( '<span class="separator"></span>' );

    $div.append( $span );

    return $div;

}
```

To transform your code, you can use something like:

```
cleanAndBuild( $( '#adv' ) );

function sliceIt( $divToSlide ) {

    var html = $divToSlide.html();
    var sliceStart = 0;
    var i = 0;
    var slices = [];

    while ( true ) {

        // getting the index to slice to.
        var sliceEnd = html.indexOf( '</span>' ) + 7;

        // -1 +7  (-1 not found, 7 of </span> size (in chars)
        if ( sliceEnd == 6 ) {
            break;
        }

        // inserting the new slice
        slices.push( html.substring( sliceStart, sliceEnd ) );

        // removing sliced piece
        html = html.substring( sliceEnd, html.length );

    }

    return slices;

}

function cleanAndBuild( $divToCleanAndBuild ) {

    // getting the slices...
    var slices = sliceIt( $divToCleanAndBuild );

    // cleaning the main container
    $divToCleanAndBuild.html( "" );

    // iterating over the slices, creating a new div, putting the slice inside it and
    // appending it to the container
    slices.forEach( function( el ) {

        var $slideDiv = $( '<div class="slide"></div>' );
        $slideDiv.append( el );
        $divToCleanAndBuild.append( $slideDiv );

    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use wrap to wrap your span element with div

e.g.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('#adv').html());
    $('.separator').wrap('<div class="slide">');
    alert($('#adv').html());
});
```

Let me create a quick fiddle and show the desired result

Comment: guys u dont have to be that mean :) with minuses

Comment: thats true ... I just saw that ... it wouldn't wrap the content ... it would just wrap the span ... I misread the html .. I thought he wanted to move the content in the span to the div that will surround it

Comment: @venom: Did you +1 this answer?

Comment: @thesystem yes, is it bad?

Comment: @venom: To upvote a non working answer isn't helpful to... well to anyone I guess. Please try to not take the voting as being mean/nice. It's only there to rate the quality of the post.

Comment: @thesystem i see, but i didnt accept it as the true one also, so it is not right anyway, thus i upvote for the help and try